# Additional import for duration/minutes DSL to work

Tags: gatling

The below is giving me a compilation error

```
setUp(
    scn.inject(
      constantUsersPerSec(10) during(30 seconds)
    )
 )
```

Getting below compilation error in IDE

```
Cannot resolve symbol seconds.
```

Am running gradle on IntelliJ and do not copy the simulations to gatling folders.
Any additional import required ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
```

Comment: +1  but how normal mortal used to alt + enter (of Intellij which does not give sensible suggestion to import it) supposed to know that, really love Gatling, idea to make it in Scala is "WOW", offer your DSL in Kotlin pls you will have influx of new clients. ;-)